# Can't output any information about a new user created within script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that will create and add an user to certain groups in Active Directory. If I tell the script to create an Active Directory user named 'John Smith' using the `New-AdUser` cmdlet, I can't use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet to pull information about 'John Smith' until AFTER the script has finished executing. In my case, I would like the script to output that 'John Smith' was created before the script terminates to show successful creation of the user.

Comment: `$newlyCreatedUser = New-ADUser "JohnSmith" -PassThru`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `New-ADUser` doesn't return information about the created account. You can change that by using the parameter `-PassThru`.

```
$user = New-ADUser ... -PassThru
```

If you just need the information if the account was created: use the automatic variable `$?` to check if the cmdlet ran successfully or not.

```
New-ADUser ...
if ($?) {
  'Account created.'
} else {
  'Account creation failed.'
}
```